# How do I add new columns to an existing hdf5 file in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I have a large dataset with about 100 columns (54 million rows). I cannot process all in memory, I want to process column by column and store the output in a single hdf5 file. However, I am really struggling with this. I keep getting error when I try to use:

```
store = pd.HDF5Store('file.h5', mode='a') 
# using an existing h5 file
store.put(key, column_frame, append=True) 
# also tried .append
```

I keep getting this error: `“cannot match existing table structure”`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you don't have enough RAM to create a dataframe with 54M rows and 100 columns. Some questions: How are you going to incrementally load the data so it fits in memory? Also, how will you use the data once it is saved to an HDF5 file? (again, since it all won't fit in memory) IMHO, how you load and process the data will impact how you write and read that data.

After reading the documentation and running some simple tests, it's not clear (to me) that you can append columns to an existing table in an HDF5 file (with Pandas or PyTables). This appears to be an HDF5 limitation with "Tables" (used for 2d heterogeneous data, similar to a Pandas dataframe). When I tried to append a dataframe series as a new column, I got the same error message as you.

Have you considered processing in batches of rows (say 1M rows at a time)? There are several examples that show how to append rows. If you use this method, you can create a single HDF5 dataset (Table) with 100 columns and 54M rows.

There is a way to write columns of data -- but you have to a seperate dataset ('key' in Pandas lingo) for each column. The following code shows how to do it. It writes the data, then reads it back into a new dataframe. (It also uses 2 different methods to write the entire dataframe to 2 other files so you can compare the values.)

**Code below:**

```
dates = ['2021-08-01','2021-08-02','2021-08-03','2021-08-04','2021-08-05',
         '2021-08-06','2021-08-07','2021-08-08','2021-08-09','2021-08-10' ]
precip = [ 0.0, 0.02, 0.0, 0.12, 0.0, 0.0, 1.11, 0.0, 0.0,  0.05]
temps = [ 80.0, 71.2, 77.5, 85.4, 83.3, 90.0, 78.9, 80.1, 72.4, 88.8]
weather_df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': dates, 'precip': precip, 'temps': temps})

# write entire dataframe to 1 Table with pd.HDFStore()
with pd.HDFStore('file1-a.h5', mode='w') as store1:
    store1.put("weather_data", weather_df, format='table')

# write entire dataframe to 1 Table with df.to_hdf()
weather_df.to_hdf('./file1-b.h5', 'weather_data', mode='w', format='table')    

# write each series to a different Table with pd.HDFStore()
with pd.HDFStore('file2.h5', mode='w') as store2:
    store2.put('dates', weather_df['dates'], format='table')

with pd.HDFStore('file2.h5', mode='a') as store2:
    store2.put('precip', weather_df['precip'])

with pd.HDFStore('file2.h5', mode='a') as store2:
    store2.append('temps', weather_df['temps'])

# load the HDF5 data into a new dataframe
with pd.HDFStore('file2.h5', mode='r') as store3:
    w_df = pd.DataFrame({'dates': store3.get('dates'), 
                         'precip': store3.get('precip'), 
                         'temps': store3.get('temps')  })
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Yes, the issue is that I do not have enough RAM to load all the data in the memory. I am using DASK dataframe to load and analyse the data. Eventually I realized the only way seems to be adding rows. The 'key' option makes it difficult to then calculate and compare feature statistics easily since I will have to load each feature separately rather than in 1 dataframe. I will use the row addition option. Thank you once again.

Comment: RE: "_I have to load each feature separately rather than in 1 dataframe_" -- look at the last 4 lines in my code. This loads 3 'keys' (columns) into 1 dataframe. The only limitation to # of 'keys' is having enough memory to hold them.